# Domain of $(x+1)^x$

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to find the domain of this function $f(x)=(x+1)^x$ , could you help me?
Fun fact: I was trying to find the answer of some sites that solve functions and I got 2 different answers, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: $a^x$ is not really defined when $a<0$.

Comment: Usually we can't see where you are confused unless you post the answers and how you arrived at them ;)

Comment: The two answers were: $x \in \mathbb{R} $ and the second one $x \ge -1 $

Comment: I don't get why the "largest possible domain" is not $\mathbb{R}$ . If I put -4 instead of x it would result in f(-4) = (-4 + 1)^-4 = 0.01234 and so on

Answer (score 4):

We can't ask what the domain of a function is. The domain is provided with the function. For example, we could have $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g:[0,1] \to\mathbb R$ with both defined as $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x$. It makes no sense to ask what the domain of a function $h(x) = x$ is.

For questions like these, what they usually have in mind is: what is the largest possible domain?

As is mentioned already, $a^x$ is ill defined for $a<0$ so at the very least, we should have $x+1\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is an abbreviation for $\text{e}^{g(x)\ln(f(x))}.$ Does this help you, taking into account the domain of the logarithm?